# Can Python Flair interpret discontinuous annotations?

Tags: python, bert-language-model

I'm working on training a sequential labeling model in Python Flair. My raw text data has concept phrases that I want the model to be able to identify that are in some cases represented by a set of tokens that are not continuous, with words in between. An example is "potassium and magnesium replacement" where "potassium replacement" is one concept that is represented by discontinuous tokens, and "magnesium replacement" is another concept which is continuous yet overlaps the first. 
I trained another Flair model where all concepts could be represented by a single token, and building corpus CoNLL files for that data was pretty straight forward. In the case, the discontinuous and overlapping concepts bring up 3 questions:

1. Does Flair sequential labeling model recognize multi-token concepts, like "magnesium replacement" as a single concept, if I mark it appropriately in CoNLL file as:

"magnesium B-CONC1

replacement I-CONC1"

2. Does it recognize discontinuous concepts as "potassium replacement" in the phrase above:

"potassium B-CONC2

and O

magnesium O

replacement I-CONC2"

3. How can I represent overlapping concepts in CoNLL file? Is there some alternative way of representing corpus with raw text and a list of start/end indices?

PS It must be pretty clear in the context, but by word concept, I mean a single- or multi-token tag/term that I'm trying to train the model to identify.

I appreciate your advice or information

Answer (score 0):

Flair does not support discontinuous and overlapping annotations. 
See more at https://github.com/zalandoresearch/flair/issues/824#issuecomment-504322361